# Log on service property

Tags: windows-7

There is a property "`Log on as`" when one use `services.msc` utility to view registered services.

1. What is the sytntax of field "`This account`"? For e.g. what does `NT
   AUTHORITY\LocalService` means?
2. What does service account really mean and what impact on the service
   itself it has? For. e.g. having `Log on as` set to `.\Derek` means
   that the service is only run when user named `Derek` is logged in?
   Or maybe the service is always started no matter with user is logged
   in but the service will have permisions to system resources just
   like the Derek user itself have?
3. Can You provide an example case for setting `Log on as` propery to
   specified user account (for e.g. `"Mark"` user) instead of default
   `Local system account`?

Comment: This sounds quite a bit like a homework question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does service account really mean and what impact on the service itself it has?

It's how the service "logs in" to the OS.

In services it mainly exists for security purposes, but it still means the same thing as regular user accounts mean to programs: it defines what *access* to the system you'll have.

For example, the folder `C:\Users\Ringger81` has "access control lists" which say that user `Ringger81` can read & change those files, but other users cannot. So if you log in to Windows as `Ringger81` you get access to those files, but other accounts (e.g. family) won't have any.

If a service is running as user `Ringger81`, that works *exactly the same way.*

(Not only files have ACLs, but also processes, devices, registry keys, printers, ... many other kinds of objects. That's why Windows has Users and Administrators, as well as the "Do you want allow this app to make changes" prompt.)

> What is the sytntax of field "This account"? For g.e. what does NT AUTHORITY\LocalService means?

In all of Windows NT series, user accounts are named like `<DOMAIN>\<username>`. The domain describes where the account comes from, and can be:

- On standalone (workgroup) PCs, it's the computer name – since each computer has its own user accounts.
- On domain-joined (Active Directory) PCs, *local* accounts are the same as above, but *domain* accounts are of course prefixed with the AD "short domain name". So the same computer could have `JOES-PC\Joe` (local) and `MYCOMPANY\Joe` (from AD).
- The special domain `NT AUTHORITY` is for various [built-in accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005(v=vs.85).aspx) that come with every Windows installation. For example, `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is the most privileged account (even above Administrators) and is used by core Windows services. `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService` is similar but *slightly* restricted.
- The shortcut `.` (e.g. `.\Joe`) means a local account on *this* computer; the dot gets replaced by the computer name.

> Can You provide an example case for setting Log on as propery to specified user account (for e.g. "Mark" user) instead of default Local system account?

Letting services run as "Local System" can be risky. They have full unrestricted access to the computer (again, even more than Administrators).

Let's say you install the Apache web server (via XAMPP or whatever) and configure it to host a small website. In the past, both Apache itself and popular website platforms (such as Wordpress) have had plenty of bugs letting a visitor modify files they shouldn't, or even trick the website into running programs/commands on the server.

If Apache were running on its own dedicated account, the damage would be limited to what its account can do: a hacker could perhaps delete the website's files or disable Apache entirely, but nothing more. If they installed malware, it would be easy to clean up.

But if Apache were running as "Local System", a hacker finding a security hole could do *anything* to the server, e.g. steal your personal files, lock you out entirely, or even delete the entire disk's contents.

Note that the example above has a *dedicated* account, since it provides the most protection. Letting services run under a "human" account is not very useful.